# Nested SELECT is hanging my SQL statement

Tags: mysql

I'm running a statement that's selecting stock market data from three tables. The last part of the statement is running a SELECT max(date) on a table that contains rows of stock data that is dated. I need the last date for a chosen stock from this table (tbl_asxd_extended.date). The problem is the statement just hangs and I can't work out why.

If I separate the statements, up to the final SELECT and run them independently they run fine! They just don't play well together when combined.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this one.

```
SELECT tbl_asxd_extended.close, tbl_asxd_extended.mcapintra, tbl_asxco.industry, tbl_asxco.company, tbl_watchlist.* 
FROM tbl_watchlist 
INNER JOIN tbl_asxco ON tbl_asxco.symbol = tbl_watchlist.symbol 
INNER JOIN tbl_asxd_extended ON tbl_asxd_extended.symbol = tbl_watchlist.symbol 
WHERE user_email='testuser@test.com' 
  AND tbl_asxd_extended.date = 
     (SELECT max(tbl_asxd_extended.date) FROM tbl_asxd_extended 
      WHERE tbl_watchlist.symbol = tbl_asxd_extended.symbol)
```

Here is an 'EXPLAIN' of the statement

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     tbl_watchlist   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    9   Using where
1   PRIMARY     tbl_asxco   eq_ref  symbol_2,symbol     symbol_2    32  func    1   Using where
1   PRIMARY     tbl_asxd_extended   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2195    Using where; Using join buffer
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  tbl_asxd_extended   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2195    Using where
```

Comment: An uncorrelated subquery will probably perform better than a correlated one.

Comment: You've accepted drivel as an answer. Just sayin ;-)

Comment: If you've got something constructive to add I'd be delighted to read it.

Comment: You didn't like my answer then? Either way, it doesn't alter the fact that the accepted answer is twaddle.

Comment: I see your post now thank you for taking time to write that. Well, look at it this way. Previously my statement didn't work and now (with an uppercase MAX) it does. This was the key question and the person who answered first resolved my key issue. That's why I accepted.

Comment: The MySQL command interface is entirely case insensitive, so that can have no bearing on the matter. The two queries are identical. If the second performs faster than the first, it's because of caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SELECT tbl_asxd_extended.close, tbl_asxd_extended.mcapintra, tbl_asxco.industry, tbl_asxco.company, tbl_watchlist.* 
FROM tbl_watchlist 
INNER JOIN tbl_asxco ON tbl_asxco.symbol = tbl_watchlist.symbol 
INNER JOIN tbl_asxd_extended ON tbl_asxd_extended.symbol = tbl_watchlist.symbol 
WHERE user_email='testuser@test.com' 
  AND tbl_asxd_extended.date = 
     (SELECT MAX(tbl_asxd_extended.date) FROM tbl_asxd_extended 
      WHERE tbl_watchlist.symbol = tbl_asxd_extended.symbol)
```

this will solve your problem as you're using the max() instead of MAX();

And if possible execute last select query first and store it in any variable say result and just assign result variable to the AND part condition matching

Comment: Ah yes changing to 'MAX' worked. The statement runs quite slowly but I'll try to speed it up with your 2nd suggestion. OK, so what was happening when it was lower case max? I would have expected some sort of syntax error feedback from mysql?

Answer (score 0):

An uncorrelated subquery usually outperforms a correlated one:

```
SELECT e.close
     , e.mcapintra
     , s.industry
     , s.company
     , w.* 
  FROM tbl_watchlist w
  JOIN tbl_asxco a
    ON a.symbol = w.symbol 
  JOIN tbl_asxd_extended e
    ON e.symbol = w.symbol
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT symbol
            , MAX(date) date
         FROM tbl_asxd_extended 
        GROUP 
           BY symbol
     ) x 
    ON x.symbol = e.symbol
   AND x.date = e.date
 WHERE user_email = 'testuser@test.com'
```

Further performance improvements may be gained by providing the EXPLAIN for the above together with CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables.